# Can't access Azure SQL database with Visual Studio but can with SSMS

Tags: visual-studio, azure, connection, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to connect to an SQL database hosted on Azure from a function app I'm building in Visual Studio but I'm getting the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
> Provider, error: 0 - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way
> forbidden by its access permissions.)

I can connect from the same PC using SSMS without a problem. I've tried connecting to the database using data connections in server explorer in VS but I'm getting the same error. If I connect to Azure with my account in server explorer it shows me a selection of services including SQL databases but there are none listed underneath although my account does have access to the database.

Are there any hidden gotchas I'm missing or settings within VS? I've also tried adding my client IP in the firewall settings but that didn't make a difference either.

Comment: Azure SQL Database is by default secured with firewall. You have to whitelist the IP address that you want to grant access to the database.

Comment: @AnkushJain I've done this already and it didn't made a difference. I'm wondering why Visual Studio is struggling to connect but SSMS from the same machine is happy. If the IP wasn't whitelisted surely I wouldn't be able to connect from either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more testing it turned out to be the client firewall that was blocking VS and VS Code from connecting to Azure SQL. It seems there was already an exception for SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

The error message states "Verify that the instance name is correct"

It could be that the SSMS is automatically creating a fully qualified name once you say that it is an azure database.

If you use the short name from Visual Studio, then you cannot connect to the SQL server.

For example "myserver.database.windows.net" versus "myserver".

Comment: I'm using the fully qualified name so I don't think it's that. I'm using the connection string provided within Azure.

Comment: Can you post your connection string (without the password)